# Why do we use only the positive root when differentiating an inverse trig function whose inside is linear?

Tags: calculus

I'm taking calc 1, and I'm struggling with these types of problems.  Example:  differentiate $y=\sin^{-1}(-4x-1)$

I think I understand how to solve these problems, but my answers typically have $\pm$ roots, like in this example: ${y}'=\frac{-4}{\pm \sqrt{-16x^{2}-8x}}$

However, I'm taking this course through Outlier and their system always marks this wrong. They want only the *positive* root in the denominator.  i.e. ${y}'=\frac{-4}{\sqrt{-16x^{2}-8x}}$

Why is this - is this just an oversight in their system, or am I missing some logic here that lets me eliminate the negative root as a possible answer?

Note: domain is all real numbers

**Here is my workflow:**

First, invert the function...

${y}=\sin^{-1}(-4x-1)\Rightarrow-4x-1=\sin y$

Then, differentiate the equality...

${\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} x}}[-4x-1]=-4$

${\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} x}}[\sin y]=\cos y(y')$

Then, use trig identities to get terms we can substitute to get terms of $x$

$\sin^{2} y+\cos^{2} y=1$

$\cos^{2} y=1-\sin^{2} y$

$\cos y=\pm \sqrt{1-\sin^{2} y}$

Finally, plug it all back in to the expression and simplify terms to get the answer...

${\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} x}}=\frac{-4}{\pm \sqrt{-16x^{2}-8x}}$

Comment: $w=\sin^{-1}x$ has range $[-\pi/2,\pi/2].$ $\cos w\geq0$ on that domain.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following. I mean, I understand what you're saying about the range of sin - but I'm not sure how it eliminates the negative root from this problem.  If we're looking at the identity $/sin^{2} y +/cos^{2} y = 1$, y is the indepedent variable in the expression, so y can be any real number.  So that is the domain - any real number, and the range of cos is -1 to 1 over that domain.  So how does that eliminate the negative root?  I'm not trying to say you're wrong - I'm just not understanding.  FWIW, it's been 20 years since I've taken trigonemetry...

Comment: How could there possibly be *two* different derivatives? The graph of the function cannot have a positive *and* a negative slope at the same point simultaneously...

Comment: Hans, that makes sense to me.  I think I understand this now.  Thanks!